# Get serial number on a iPad

Tags: ipad, ios5

I would like to get an iPads serial number? I've found two ways this can be archived, the first is using an uuid, but this isn't the best solution. Because I need the serial number as it stand on the back of the iPad.

The other solution is to implement a deprecated github project :/

So isn't it possible to the retrieve serial number, that is printed on the back of the iPad?

If it isn't possible, is this because the serial number is protected somehow, so I can't miss use it?

[UPDATE]
If it's not possible to get the serial number is it possible to get the device name then?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: whats for? you want do get something unique for every device or get the serial number?

Comment: It's not important that it's total unique. I just need a easy way to identify a device, so it's easy for the user to add the device to our database. This could be the name or serial number, just a simple id a user can read somewhere on his device..

Answer (score 0):

The serial number of the iOS device can be retrieved. But I'm not sure if Apple allows this for the apps that go into the AppStore.

You will need these imports:

```
#import <sys/utsname.h>
#import <dlfcn.h>
```

The following method will retrieve the device **serial number**.

```
+(NSString *) getSerialNumber
{
    NSString *serialNumber = nil;

    void *IOKit = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit", RTLD_NOW);
    if (IOKit)
    {
        mach_port_t *kIOMasterPortDefault = dlsym(IOKit, "kIOMasterPortDefault");
        CFMutableDictionaryRef (*IOServiceMatching)(const char *name) = dlsym(IOKit, "IOServiceMatching");
        mach_port_t (*IOServiceGetMatchingService)(mach_port_t masterPort, CFDictionaryRef matching) = dlsym(IOKit, "IOServiceGetMatchingService");
        CFTypeRef (*IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty)(mach_port_t entry, CFStringRef key, CFAllocatorRef allocator, uint32_t options) = dlsym(IOKit, "IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty");
        kern_return_t (*IOObjectRelease)(mach_port_t object) = dlsym(IOKit, "IOObjectRelease");

        if (kIOMasterPortDefault && IOServiceGetMatchingService && IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty && IOObjectRelease)
        {
            mach_port_t platformExpertDevice = IOServiceGetMatchingService(*kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice"));
            if (platformExpertDevice)
            {
                CFTypeRef platformSerialNumber = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(platformExpertDevice, CFSTR("IOPlatformSerialNumber"), kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
                if (CFGetTypeID(platformSerialNumber) == CFStringGetTypeID())
                {
                    serialNumber = [NSString stringWithString:(__bridge NSString*)platformSerialNumber];
                    CFRelease(platformSerialNumber);
                }
                IOObjectRelease(platformExpertDevice);
            }
        }
        dlclose(IOKit);
    }
    return serialNumber;
}
```

Getting the **Name** of the devices that is configured in the settings is quite easy. Try the following method.

```
+(NSString *) getDeviceName
{
    //RETURNS THE DEVICE NAME CONFIGURED IN SETTINGS
    NSString *nameString = [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
    return nameString;
}
```